# AngularJS DOM selection inside tabset

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm a bit of a Angular newbie, but have run into what seems to be a pretty dumb problem.

I've created a directive that requires me to find specific DOM element. This works nice and good, except that once I place my directive inside the bootstrap UI tabset, bad things happen. Basically I think since the tabset directive uses custom HTML elements (i.e. , DOM selection no longer works. I've also tried using a jQuery selector, which also fails. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
--html
<body ng-controller="mainController">

<tabset>
    <tab heading="Title 1">
        <my-directive id="myWidget"></my-directive>
    </tab>
</tabset

</body> 

--js
app.directive('registrationGrid', function() {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        var element = document.getElementById("myWidget");
        //do some stuff here
}
})
```

There has to be an easy way around this, but I'm at a loss. I'm tempted to just update the tabs directive to work off of attributes instead of it's own element, but was hoping for an easier fix.

Comment: The beauty of a directive is that you don't have to find the element, you already have it in the link: function($scope, element...) Just use "element" and you have it. No need for the getElementById.

Comment: I guess that was too obvious for me ;) thanks!